# Play loop audio breaking the sound ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I have an audio around 3 second, and I implement it in play loop. The problem is during playing loop the audio break sound in a short time. Can anybody help me about this issue?

My code as bellow:

```
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1      
audioPlayer.currentTime = 0.0        
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()      
audioPlayer.play()
```